# Return the key of the maximum value in a dictionary base on criteria in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, max

I have the following dictionary:

```
d = {'a': {'0': 'London', '1': 'Athens', '2': 'Paris', '3': 'London'},
 'b': {'0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3, '3': 2}}
```

The keys in `d['a']` and `d['b']` are the same.

I would like to return the key with the highest value in sub-dictionary `d['b']` where it has a specific value in sub-dictionary `d['a']`.

For example, if I set as an input `'London'`, it should return `'3'`, because `'London'` is in keys `'0'` and `'3'`, and the highest values for these keys in dictionary `'b'` is under key `'3'`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options. Assuming you don't want to use a more suitable structure, you can start by finding the keys matching `London`:

```
d = {
     'a': {'0': 'London', '1': 'Athens', '2': 'Paris', '3': 'London'},
     'b': {'0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3, '3': 2}
}
a = d['a']
b = d['b']

keys = [k for k in a if a[k] == 'London']
```

Then, you can run `max` on the result:

```
max(keys, key=lambda k: b[k])
```

As a one-liner:

```
max((k for k in a if a[k] == 'London'), key=lambda k: b[k])
```

The problem with this approach is that you are looking up in a dictionary by value, which largely defeats the propose of having a dictionary. If you have the freedom to modify your dictionary `a`, reverse it:

```
from collections import defaultdict
a_better = defaultdict(list)
for v, k in a.items():
    a_better[k].append(v)
```

Now the lookup is much more straightforward:

```
max(a_better['London'], key=lambda k: b[k])
```