# Return the dictionary from a list of dictionaries with the highest value in a specific key

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following list of dictionaries in python:

```
data = [{'flag': 'one', 'timestamp': 20190710},
{'flag': 'one', 'timestamp': 20190711},
{'flag': 'two', 'timestamp': 20190712}, 
{'flag': 'two', 'timestamp': 20190709}]
```

I would like to return the dictionary with the the highest value in the key `timestamp` and with the value `one` in the key `flag`.

I have done something similar here:

[Return the key of the maximum value in a dictionary base on criteria in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627054/return-the-key-of-the-maximum-value-in-a-dictionary-base-on-criteria-in-python)

But cannot make it work in this new set-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `max()` built-in function with custom `key=`. Before that, we filter the dictionary only for items with key `'flag'` == `'one'`:

```
data = [{'flag': 'one', 'timestamp': 20190710},
{'flag': 'one', 'timestamp': 20190711},
{'flag': 'two', 'timestamp': 20190712},
{'flag': 'two', 'timestamp': 20190709}]

print(max((i for i in data if i['flag'] == 'one'), key=lambda k: k['timestamp']))
```

Prints:

```
{'flag': 'one', 'timestamp': 20190711}
```

EDIT: Quick benchmark of what's faster - doing the filtration first or finding the max in whole list:

```
from random import choice,randint

data = []
for i in range(10000):
    data.append({'flag': choice(['one', 'two']), 'timestamp': randint(1, 1_000_000)})

def fn1():
    return max(data, key=lambda x: (x["flag"] == 'one', x["timestamp"]))

def fn2():
    return max((i for i in data if i['flag'] == 'one'), key=lambda k: k['timestamp'])

from timeit import timeit

t1 = timeit(lambda: fn1(), number=1_000)
t2 = timeit(lambda: fn2(), number=1_000)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints:

```
1.5405012619994523
0.8562619980002637
```

Which means doing the filtration first is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Using `max` with custom key without iteration.

**Ex:**

```
data = [{'flag': 'one', 'timestamp': 20190710},{'flag': 'one', 'timestamp': 20190711},{'flag': 'two', 'timestamp': 20190712}, {'flag': 'two', 'timestamp': 20190709}]
print(max(data, key=lambda x: (x["flag"] == 'one', x["timestamp"])))
```

**Output:**

```
{'flag': 'one', 'timestamp': 20190711}
```